# What's the ASP.NET Webservice request lifecycle?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-services, asmx

On a regular `aspx` page, I have events such as `Page_Init`, `Page_Unload`, etc., which occur [in a well-defined order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

I have an `asmx` page providing `[WebMethod()]`s. Do similar events exist? In particular, some events that allow me to initialize some data (like `Page_Load`) and do some clean-up (like `Page_Unload`) would be extremely useful.

(As far as I can tell, the constructor of the `asmx` code-behind class seems to be called on every WebMethod request, i.e., a new instance is created for every WebMethod request, but this is just an observation and not something I've found documented somewhere...)

Comment: I would point out that this is fairly implementation-dependant information, especially considering that ASMX has pretty much been replaced by WCF, which has a totally different lifecycle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes - Otavio is correct, there is no Page events for ASMX Web Services, as they do not derive from Page.

However, The request follows the regular [ASP.NET processing pipeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx).

There is a point in the process where the relevant IHttpHandler is executed. This can be a page, a generic HTTP handler, or a web service.

This is where the web service request execution happens.

So, it really depends on what you're trying to do here. The ctor should provide a good hook-in to pre-request execution. If you're looking for something even earlier, then you will likely need to hook into a Global.asax event.

Answer (score 1):

`asmx` objects are not derived from Page, rather from `System.Web.Services.WebService`, so they will not have the events you are looking for.